# How to create dynamic folders in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code that generates file names dynamically and an example could be

```
abc_khjjkhkjh_234.xlsx
abc_poiuy_898.xlsx
xyz_kjjkkjh_345.xlsx
xyz_qweer_909.xlsx
```

Instead of publishing the files like above, I would like to create 2 folders named as `abc` & `xyz` & then keep `abc_khjjkhkjh_234.xlsx,abc_poiuy_898.xlsx` in folder `abc` & similar with `xyz`.

Comment: Could you explain the problem more fully? Or add your code

Comment: It look likes you button mashed around the right hand home key. Are you asking how to make random strings?

Answer (score 0):

For creating directories

```
import os
# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/tmp/year"

try:
   os.mkdir(path)     //Also use this  os.mkdir(path, access_rights) to give rights
except OSError:
   print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
   print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Comment: my code to publish files now is like below:                                                            with open("{0}_khjjkhkjh_234".format(name), 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(df)                                                                                 Instead I want to first create a folder abc or xyz depending on the name value & then publish respective files starting with either abc or xyz in those folders

Comment: with open(path+'/'+"{0}_khjjkhkjh_234".format(name), 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f: Now just concatenate created directory path with open

Comment: First create a directory in specific path then write file in respective directory name